# C include file behaviour

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm writing some code for an UART library. I'm using a FIFO queue to buffer IO and I have two modules FIFO.c/h and UART.c/h.
I defined some struct types that I need in order to interface with the HAL software of the platform but I'm having trouble under Eclipse in including some headers:

```
//FIFO.h

#ifndef FIFO_H
#define FIFO_H

typedef struct FIFO *FIFO;
typedef int item;

FIFO FIFO_new(int size);

void FIFO_init(FIFO f,item *buffer,int size);

int FIFO_is_empty(FIFO f);

int FIFO_is_full(FIFO f);

int FIFO_put(FIFO f,item i);

int FIFO_get(FIFO f,item *i);

void FIFO_make_empty(FIFO f);

#endif /* FIFO_H */
```

and

```
// UART.h

#ifndef UART_H
#define UART_H

#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

typedef struct
{
    UART_HandleTypeDef hal_handle;
    FIFO FIFO_buffer;                 // compiler complains
} UART_MyHandleTypeDef;

void UART_Init(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart,int buffer_size);

void UART_Transmit(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart,int datacompile);

int UART_receive(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart);

void UART_write(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart,const char *string);

#endif /* UART_H */
```

the type FIFO is a pointer to a struct that's defined in FIFO.c (it's encapsulated and I don't want to expose it to client code).

I'm including UART.h after FIFO.h in a source file so UART.h should see the typedef in FIFO.h. But the compiler is not happy with that. I'm using Eclipse for C/C++.

EDIT: the error I get from the compiler:

```
In file included from ../src/main.c:2:0:
C:/Users/l1u9c/Documents/SW4STM32/Nucleo 64 UART/inc/UART.h:9:2: error: unknown type name 'FIFO'
  FIFO FIFO_buffer;
  ^
In file included from ../src/stm32f4xx_it.c:3:0:
C:/Users/l1u9c/Documents/SW4STM32/Nucleo 64 UART/inc/UART.h:9:2: error: unknown type name 'FIFO'
  FIFO FIFO_buffer;
  ^
```

EDIT: the source file in which I'm including the headers:

```
#include "FIFO.h"
#include "UART.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

void UART_Init(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart,int buffer_size)
{
    /* intialization code in application has to fill in the hal handle fields */
    HAL_UART_Init(&uart->hal_handle);
    uart->FIFO_buffer = FIFO_new(buffer_size);
}

void UART_Transmit(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart,int data)
{
    while (FIFO_put(uart->FIFO_buffer,data) != 0)
        ;
}

int UART_Receive(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart)
{
    int data;
    while (FIFO_get(uart->FIFO_buffer,&data) != 0)
        ;
    return data;
}

void UART_write(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart,const char *string)
{
    while (*string != '\0')
        UART_Transmit(uart,*string++);
}

void UART_IRQHandler(UART_MyHandleTypeDef *uart)
{
    if (__HAL_UART_GET_IT_SOURCE(&uart->hal_handle,UART_IT_TXE))
    {

    }
    if (__HAL_UART_GET_IT_SOURCE(&uart->hal_handle,UART_IT_RXNE))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: *Always* include dependencies. Don't rely on the order of the inclusions. I.e. include  `FIFO.h` in `UART.h`. You have the inclusion guards, which will mess up all of your assumptions.

Comment: Please show us the *complete* error output, in full, unedited and including any potential informational notes.

Comment: BTW, where is the definition of `struct FIFO`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Header guards don't mess up inclusions in this case.It's a very simple inclusion tree.
Besides,something similar (including after another header in a source file) is done by the HAL driver I'm using for the platform

Comment: @EugeneSh. "the type FIFO is a pointer to a struct that's defined in FIFO.c (it's encapsulated and I don't want to expose it to client code)." 
That's not an issue since the typedef of the incomplete type should be visible.

Comment: ...and: to hide pointers type with `typedef` **is alsways a bad idea** ....

Comment: @Luca You have to declare the opaque `struct FIFO;` somewhere visible to `FIFO.h`..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't understand. All UART.h needs to know is that a FIFO type is defined (the type,not hte struct)

Comment: But how can it know it? You haven't told it...

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's in the FIFO.h that I include along with UART.h in the same UART.c (FIFO is included BEFORE so it should be visible)

Comment: @LPs I definitedly can use the same name as in C struct tags and typedef names (and variables) doesn't share the same namespace

Comment: Again. There is NO type `struct FIFO` declared *anywhere* in these header files! If you want it to be an opaque struct, you need at least this line `struct FIFO;`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. A declaration is inside the typedef. When I write typedef struct FIFO *FIFO I'm declaring an incomplete type struct FIFO and defining FIFO to be a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: OK, let's start from the beginning. Can you show your `main.c`? Also the second error hints that the *provided* file `stm32f4xx_it.c` is including `UART.h` for some reason. Have you modified it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. posted

Comment: @EugeneSh.Wow,thank you! UART.h is included in two other source files. No wonder THERE the compiler couldn't find type FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm including UART.h after FIFO.h in a source file so UART.h should see the typedef in FIFO.h.

That is not how include files work. If you have a source file that has:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

then this source file will see the definitions from `a.h` and `b.h` - in that order - but the header files themselves remain unaffected.

It is also generally accepted as a bad idea to have code that depends on the order of include files. Sometimes that is unfortunately unavoidable but such cases should be minimized and clearly explained. In your case, you should simply include `fifo.h` in `uart.h`, and your FIFO structure should be defined in `fifo.h` and not `fifo.c`. Encapsulation is good, but if you have a structure that's needed by multiple modules, it shouldn't be hidden away in a `.c` file.

Comment: In which cases it is unavoidable? Except the ones the *vendor provided* API is badly designed and cannot be modified.

Comment: The API from the ST vendor is designed this way. And this does not explain why it shouldn't work.

Comment: In your case it is *your* code which is badly designed. Yes, I know ST (and TI and others, unfortunately) are doing it too, but it is not justifying doing the same.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, but WHY do their code work in the same project and mine doesn't compile? It must be something else

Comment: @EugeneSh. Badly designed APIs (not uncommon for microcontroller code to depend on the inclusion order), or (in C++) the Microsoft precompiled header, or some embedded standards that require you to use a particular order of header files to be standards-compliant.